# Tensorflow gradient descent optimizer gives nan results

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to find mutually far apart points on the unit circle as an introduction to tensorflow. I keep getting nan results and I don't know why.

I've found several problems with my algorithm and fixed them. I've tried changing the learning rate as well as alpha and beta by orders of magnitude and still the same problem.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([4, 1], -1.0, 1.0, dtype=tf.float32, seed=42), dtype=tf.float32, name="x")
y = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1, 4], -1.0, 1.0, dtype=tf.float32, seed=43), dtype=tf.float32, name="y")

alpha = tf.constant(0.5, dtype=tf.float32, name='alpha')
beta = tf.constant(-0.25, dtype=tf.float32, name='beta')

# Error function for "on the circle"
errA = alpha * tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.abs((x*x) + (y*y) -1))

# Error function for "far apart"
# I'm sure there's a better way to do this but I couldn't figure out what it is

xstack = tf.stack([x,x,x,x], axis=0)
xt = tf.transpose(x)
yt = tf.transpose(y)
ystack = tf.stack([yt,yt,yt,yt], axis=0)
xtstack = tf.stack([xt,xt,xt,xt], axis=1)
ytstack = tf.stack([y,y,y,y], axis=1)

xs = xstack - xtstack
ys = ystack - ytstack

errB = beta * tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.sqrt(xs*xs + ys*ys))

n_epochs = 1000
learning_rate = 0.01

error = errA + errB

mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error), name="mse")

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(mse)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print("Epoch", epoch, "MSE =", mse.eval())
        sess.run(training_op)

    best_x = x.eval()
    best_y = y.eval()
```

I would hope to see MSE decreasing and a final best x and y. The actual output is

```
Epoch 0 MSE = 0.0034612082
Epoch 100 MSE = nan
Epoch 200 MSE = nan
Epoch 300 MSE = nan
Epoch 400 MSE = nan
Epoch 500 MSE = nan
Epoch 600 MSE = nan
Epoch 700 MSE = nan
Epoch 800 MSE = nan
Epoch 900 MSE = nan
```

and best x and y are all nan as well. After running the optimizer just once it becomes nan.

Comment: please check `ystack` and `ytstack`.